# Get service name from it's PID (powershell)

Tags: windows, powershell

I am having trouble solving a minor issue. So for processes, I can store its name from its $PID using the following line:

> $process_name=get-Process -id $PID |select -expand name

However, I want to run the process as a **service**. I want to complete the same operation, that is: store the service's name e.g. [service_name].exe into a variable $service_name.

The reason for this is because I want to have just one .ps1 file, that I can then turn into multiple services that uses its own .exe.config files. So that just one .ps1 file can be compiled multiple times into services such as

[service1.exe, service2.exe, service3.exe, ...]

and each service uses its corresponding .exe.config file such as

[service1.exe.config, service2.exe.config, service3.exe.config, ...]

Is there any way to do this with powershell?

Comment: I am not understanding what you want, are you just looking for the executable's name? Are you looking for all of the executables or just the one you are running? Is it this simple: "$process_name = (get-Process -id $PID).Path"?

Comment: @DBADon I want the name of the executable that is running. So for a service named service1.exe, I need to have a command that stores "service1" or "service1.exe" into variable $service_name. Similar to how the line [ $process_name=get-Process -id $PID |select -expand name ] stores the name of the executable that runs it into variable $process_name

Answer (score 3):

You can get the Service Information from Processid

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "ProcessId='$PID'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Get-WmiObject you can collect the executables:

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_service | Where-Object -Property Name -Like *wallet*).PathName
```

This example will display the executable name along with any switches. If you want to capture this to a variable try:

```
$proc_name = (Get-WmiObject win32_service | Where-Object -Property Name -Like *wallet*).PathName
```

If you need any of the expanded property information try:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -like '*wallet*'} | Select-Object -Property *
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way - those above might be more reliable?

```
$id = 5556
# (debugging) Nice little table to make sure you've got the right thing...
Get-Process | Where-Object Id -EQ $id | Select ProcessName,Id | Format-Table    
 
# Finally just hand me back the name proper
Get-Process | Where-Object Id -EQ $id | Select -Expand ProcessName 
# Depending on what you're doing with it...
# Stop-Process -Id $id
```

Comment: This will _not_ give you the service name(s).